# Which "address_component" keys of google geocode map api response should use for address, address line 2, zip code, city and state

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api, geocode

I am using google geocode map api to get the address detail.I have a separate HTML input field for address, address line 2, zip code, city and state in my form. Now,I would like to fetch the address details from the geocode map api response and then auto populate address, address line 2, zip code, city and state value in the respective input field based on `address_component` keys of API response.

```
Sample API response:
{
    address_components: [
    {
            long_name: "277",
            short_name: "277",
            types: ["street_number"]
    },
    {
            long_name: "Bedford Avenue",
            short_name: "Bedford Ave",
            types: ["route"]
    },
    {
            long_name: "Williamsburg",
            short_name: "Williamsburg",
            types: ["neighborhood", "political"]
    },
    {
            long_name: "Brooklyn",
            short_name: "Brooklyn",
            types: ["political", "sublocality",
                    "sublocality_level_1"
            ]
    },
    {
            long_name: "Kings County",
            short_name: "Kings County",
            types: ["administrative_area_level_2",
                    "political"
            ]
    },
    {
            long_name: "New York",
            short_name: "NY",
            types: ["administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
            ]
    },
    {
            long_name: "United States",
            short_name: "US",
            types: ["country", "political"]
    },
    {
            long_name: "11211",
            short_name: "11211",
            types: ["postal_code"]
    }],
    formatted_address: "277 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA"
 }
```

So currently, I am using below mapping
for US addresses and it is working fine
for US.

ADDRESS:
ADDRESS_COMPONENT KEYS - short_name - 'street_number', 'route', 'floor'

ADDRESS LINE 2:
ADDRESS_COMPONENT KEYS - short_name - 'room', 'premise', 'subpremise',
'landmark'

ZIP / POSTAL CODE:
ADDRESS_COMPONENT KEYS - short_name - 'postal_code'

CITY:
ADDRESS_COMPONENT KEYS - short_name - 'postal_town', 'locality',
'sublocality'

STATE:
ADDRESS_COMPONENT KEYS - short_name - 'administrative_area_level_1'

But when I am trying to use the same logic
for International addresses and I am getting different keys
for different countries.

Example of some of the International Geocode responses:

```
ADDRESS1:

{
    address_components: [
    {
        long_name: "810",
        short_name: "810",
        types: ["street_number"]
    },
    {
        long_name: "Dubai Fountain Street",
        short_name: "Dubai Fountain St",
        types: ["route"]
    },
    {
        long_name: "Downtown Dubai",
        short_name: "Downtown Dubai",
        types: ["political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1"]
    },
    {
        long_name: "Dubai",
        short_name: "Dubai",
        types: ["locality", "political"]
    },
    {
        long_name: "Dubai",
        short_name: "Dubai",
        types: ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
    },
    {
        long_name: "United Arab Emirates",
        short_name: "AE",
        types: ["country", "political"]
    }],
    formatted_address: "810 Dubai Fountain St - Downtown Dubai - Dubai - United Arab Emirates"
}

ADDRESS 2:
{
    address_components: [
    {
            long_name: "Nakase",
            short_name: "Nakase",
            types: ["political", "sublocality",
                    "sublocality_level_2"
            ]
    },
    {
            long_name: "Mihama Ward",
            short_name: "Mihama Ward",
            types: ["political", "sublocality",
                    "sublocality_level_1"
            ]
    },
    {
            long_name: "Chiba",
            short_name: "Chiba",
            types: ["locality", "political"]
    },
    {
            long_name: "Chiba",
            short_name: "Chiba",
            types: ["administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
            ]
    },
    {
            long_name: "Japan",
            short_name: "JP",
            types: ["country", "political"]
    },
    {
            long_name: "261-0023",
            short_name: "261-0023",
            types: ["postal_code"]
    }],
    formatted_address: "Nakase, Mihama Ward, Chiba, 261-0023, Japan"
 }



 ADDRESS 3:
 {
    address_components: [
    {
            long_name: "#####",
            short_name: "#####",
            types: ["plus_code"]
    },
    {
            long_name: "Hangzhou",
            short_name: "Hangzhou",
            types: ["locality", "political"]
    },
    {
            long_name: "Zhejiang",
            short_name: "Zhejiang",
            types: ["administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
            ]
    },
    {
            "long_name": "China",
            "short_name": "CN",
            types: ["country", "political"]
    }],
    formatted_address: "######, Hangzhou, Zhejiang, China"
 }
```

Is there any generic or common or standard rule which I can follow to map `adddress_components` keys
for international countries
for these values(address, address line 2, zipcode city and state) ?

Comment: My understanding is that there is no generic, common or standard rule, each country has its own mapping (which probably isn't documented anywhere, or if it is, it is documented in the data source for that country).

Comment: That is indeed the case for nearly all the Google Maps APIs. The newer Address Validation API introduced a different type of address that does better when it comes to aligning with what the "city or town" is in each region: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/validateAddress#PostalAddress